# Ext.js - Open all external links in a new tab

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

Maybe somebody has already faced with this problem.
**I need to make all external links to open in a new browser tab.**

The solution seems to be easy: just adding `target="_blank"` to each link with external domain, but how can I implement it in a nice way, because whole app is written in Ext.js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to answer my own question, because maybe it will be useful for anybody.
The only way to catch all clicks on the links is to control body clicks (as triclozan wrote in his answer). 
This code will modify every link after clicking and will open it in the new window:

```
Ext.getBody().addListener('click', function (event, el) {
    var clickTarget = event.target;

    if (clickTarget.href && clickTarget.href.indexOf(window.location.origin) === -1) {
        clickTarget.target = "_blank";
    }
});
```

Hope this code will save few hours of googling for somebody with the same problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You change target attributes with JavaScript:

```
var tlinks = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i=0;i<tlinks.length;i++){
        if (tlinks[i].href.indexOf('http://www.yourownurlhere.com') == -1) {
            tlinks[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');
        }                
    }
```

Remember to replace "yourownurlhere.com" with your actual url

Answer (score 2):

The trick can be done with event delegation.

```
Ext.select('body').on('click', function (e, el) {
    el.target = '_blank';
}, null, {delegate: 'a'});
```

Note that if you write just

```
Ext.select('a').on('click', function (e, el) {
    el.target = '_blank';
});
```

then you apply handler only to existing links. However, delegation also handles elements created afterwards. If you want such behaivor for links included only in certain container, you may change '**body**' to any selector that matches that container.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/triclozan/TKPu5/)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do :

window.open("Your link");